# catkin_make error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS and I'm having problems using the catkin_make command. When used I get the error below.Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here's my code below:

```
michelle@michelle-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/michelle/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/michelle/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/michelle/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/michelle/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/michelle/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/michelle/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j1 -l1" in "/home/michelle/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  1%] Building CXX object ros_essentials_cpp/CMakeFiles/open_copy_cpp.dir/src/topic03_perception/cpp/open_copy.cpp.o
/home/michelle/catkin_ws/src/ros_essentials_cpp/src/topic03_perception/cpp/open_copy.cpp:1:10: fatal error: highgui.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <highgui.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [ros_essentials_cpp/CMakeFiles/open_copy_cpp.dir/build.make:63: ros_essentials_cpp/CMakeFiles/open_copy_cpp.dir/src/topic03_perception/cpp/open_copy.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:474: ros_essentials_cpp/CMakeFiles/open_copy_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354843/catkin_make-error/) by [Michelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/55765/michelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To build the code, the compiler looks for a header file named "highgui.h", but it is not able to locate it. This is most likely due to some missing instruction in the CMakeLists.txt file, which is not telling the compiler where the file can be located. Without knowing what you are trying to compile, it is a little hard to give an exact answer. However, here there are three candidate ways to solve the issue:

**Case 1: the header is part of your package**

According to the guidelines, the headers of a package named `pkg_name` should be located in the folder `include/pkg_name`. In this case, it is common to write in the CMakeLists.txt the following (after `catkin_package` but before any `add_executable`):

```
include_directories(include)
```

You would then be able to locate headers by writing something like: `#include <pkg_name/header.h>`. Note that, since in your error the missing header is not in this form, this case is not likely the one you need to focus on. However, I put it here for completeness.

**Case 2: the header is part of another catkin package**

Let's say that the header belongs to `some_pkg`. In **you** CmakeLists, you should locate the line in which you find other catkin packages, and make sure that `some_pkg` is there:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS some_pkg ...)
```

Then, you must make sure that the headers from catkin packages are visible:

```
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

**Case 3: the header is part of another non-catkin package**

Well, in this case there are too many possibilities to discuss... If you are "lucky", the header is part of some package `external_pkg` that can be easily located and included using CMake:

```
find_package(external_pkg REQUIRED)
...
include_directories(${external_pkg_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

---

Originally posted by [ffusco](https://answers.ros.org/users/36264/ffusco/) with karma: 271 on 2020-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0